# How to Calculate the average of Array Kotlin Android

Tags: android, arrays, function, kotlin, calculator

I am very new to Kotlin and Android. I am trying to calculate the average of the values in my Array in the function "array" but i'm not very sure how to do it. I have created a function called "average" which I want to calculate the average of the array within. Any help would be very appreciated. Below is all of my source code.

```
class MainActivity2 : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var addnumber: EditText
    private lateinit var storednumber: TextView
    private lateinit var output: TextView
    private lateinit var addbutton: Button
    private lateinit var clearbutton: Button
    private lateinit var averagebutton: Button
    private lateinit var minmaxbutton: Button


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)

        addnumber = findViewById(R.id.et_addNum)
        storednumber = findViewById(R.id.stored_tv)
        output = findViewById(R.id.answer2_tv)
        addbutton = findViewById(R.id.addNum_btn)
        clearbutton = findViewById(R.id.clear_btn)
        averagebutton = findViewById(R.id.average_btn)
        minmaxbutton = findViewById(R.id.minMax_btn)


        addbutton.setOnClickListener {
            array()

        }

        clearbutton.setOnClickListener {
            clear()

        }

        clearbutton.setOnClickListener {
            average()

        } 
    }
    private fun array() {
        val ed = findViewById<View>(R.id.et_addNum) as EditText
        var text = ed.text.toString()
        val array: List<String> = text.split(",")
        
        for (element in array) {
            Log.e("elements", element)

            storednumber.setText(array.toString())
        }
    }

    
    private fun clear() {
        storednumber.setText(null)
    }

    
    private fun average() {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use `toIntOrNull` on your strings to convert them to numbers - personally I'd do that *before* you store them in the array, since part of reading the user input is validation and error handling. That way you can have a nice neat `Array<Int>` that you can work out an average for. Since this is homework you should probably learn how to average numbers yourself! If you have no idea then start off learning about `for` loops and think how you could use that behaviour to add things up, before you divide by the number of items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your answer:

```
    private fun array() {
        var text = addnumber.text.toString()
        val array: List<String> = text.split(",")
        var intArray = mutableListOf<Int>()
        for (element in array) {
            intArray.add(element.toInt())
        }
        average(intArray)
    }
    
    private fun average(list: List<Int>) {
        val myAverage = list.average() // here is the average you can use it.
        output.text = myAverage.toString()
    }
```

Comment: Instead of printing the average to log, how would I rather output it as a TextView called "output"

Comment: I'm not sure because I get "no value passed for parameter "list" in my "averagebutton.setOnClickListener"

Comment: I edited my answer, use same code, it will work. And Log is just help us to see if we are doing it right or wrong, you should know how to use it too.

Comment: What does the (list: List<Int>) do? I ask because my plan was to do the average calculation in the clearbutton.setOnClickListener {}

Comment: Nevermind. I figured it out. I just needed to move my Average function up next to the array function. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

As you're using `Kotlin`, you should consider using the [`Extension`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html) function, `average()`, like below:

```
arrayOf(4, 34, 5, 44).average()
```

OR

You can create your custom `average()` method, like below:

```
fun average(arr: Array<Int>): Double {
        return if (arr.isNullOrEmpty()) 0.0
        else {
            var sum = 0.0
            for (i in arr) {
                sum += i
            }
            sum / arr.size
        }
    }
```